# Spring boot + JPA dynamic datasource

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have a situation, where I need to create a db connection based on user input and this created connection should be used for all transactions till that particular user logs out. I need to do this in Spring boot + JPA. By default I take the connection details from a yaml file at server start up.

I am confused how to create a new data source and use it for whole session.

I am new to spring boot and JPA. Can someone please help me with an example.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the same database when a user logs in ? Which database are you using, Oracle ?

Comment: You want to create a DB connection when the user logs in and use the same connection until he logs out. Is this your requirement? You can try [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-session-jdbc)

Comment: @rjdkolb - i am trying to connect to same database and in this case it is Oracle DB.

Comment: So you can use an Oracle proxy user. It will give you the performance of a real pool, but each user will have their specific rights on the database. Audit trails will also pick up the user proxied to. http://www.andrejkoelewijn.com/blog/2005/09/12/oracle-proxy-users-by-example/

Answer (score 0):

***This is not a quick fix and it may take a day or so to implement correctly***, but using [Oracle proxy connection](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e12265/toc.htm) gives you the speed of a normal JDBC pool but each user will have their specific rights on the database. Audit trails will also pick up the user proxied to.

The Spring logged in user is used to determine which user to Proxy as.

You will need two dependencies downloaded from [Oracle JDBC page](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-ucp-122-3110062.html).
Make sure the versions are the same. Install them in your Maven repo.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ucp</artifactId>
    <version>12.2.0.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    <version>12.2.0.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Provide a datasource for Spring.

```
import oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPool;
import oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolAdapter;
import oracle.ucp.admin.UniversalConnectionPoolManager;
import oracle.ucp.admin.UniversalConnectionPoolManagerImpl;
import oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource;
import oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceFactory;

@Bean
@SneakyThrows
public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
    final PoolDataSource pds = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();
    UniversalConnectionPoolManager mgr = UniversalConnectionPoolManagerImpl.getUniversalConnectionPoolManager();

    pds.registerConnectionLabelingCallback(new MyProxyConnectionLabelingCallback("MY_NOPRIV"));//you can make this any name you want
    DataSource result = new ProxyDelegatingDataSource(pds, getNoPrivilegesUser());

    mgr.createConnectionPool((UniversalConnectionPoolAdapter) pds);
    mgr.startConnectionPool(PROXY_UCP_NAME);
    return result;
}
```

Implement [ConnectionLabelingCallback](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e12265/label.htm#BABGJEEA) and understand what cost does.

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection;
import oracle.ucp.ConnectionLabelingCallback;
import oracle.ucp.jdbc.LabelableConnection;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

public class MyProxyConnectionLabelingCallback implements ConnectionLabelingCallback {

    public static final String USER_PROXY = "USER_PROXY";

    private final String noPrivilegesUser;

    public ProxyConnectionLabelingCallback(String noPrivilegesUser) {
        this.noPrivilegesUser = noPrivilegesUser;
    }

    @Override
    public int cost(Properties reqLabels, Properties currentLabels) {
        final Object request = reqLabels.get(USER_PROXY);
        final Object current = currentLabels.get(USER_PROXY);
        if (request.equals(current)) {
            //Same user
            return 0;
        }
        if (noPrivilegesUser.equals(current)) {
            //No Priv User. No Little Cost
            return 1;
        }
        //Different user request

        return 1000;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean configure(Properties reqLabels, Object conn) {
        try {
            LabelableConnection lConn = (LabelableConnection) conn;
            String userName = getUserName(noPrivilegesUser);
            final Properties connectionLabels = lConn.getConnectionLabels();
            if (connectionLabels == null) {
                setProxy((OracleConnection) conn, noPrivilegesUser, userName, null);
                lConn.applyConnectionLabel(USER_PROXY, userName);
                return true;
            }
            Object currentLabel = connectionLabels.get(USER_PROXY);
            if (!userName.equals(currentLabel)) {
                setProxy((OracleConnection) conn, currentLabel, userName, null);
                lConn.applyConnectionLabel(USER_PROXY, userName);
            } else {
                //Label match, good
            }
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException| RuntimeException sExp) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static String getUserName(String noPrivilegesUser) {
        final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();// you are logged with this user using Spring Security
        if ((authentication == null)) {
            //Not logged in returning non privileged user
            return noPrivilegesUser;
        }
        Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
        if (principal.equals("anonymousUser")) {
            //Not logged in returning non privileged user
            return noPrivilegesUser;
        }
        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            final String username = ((UserDetails) (principal)).getUsername();
            //proxy connection to user  username
            return username;
        } else {
            return principal.toString();
        }
    }

    public void setProxy(OracleConnection oraCon, Object currentLabel, String proxyUserName, String proxyPassword) throws SQLException {
        if (oraCon.isProxySession()) {
            oraCon.close(OracleConnection.PROXY_SESSION);
        }

        Properties proxyProperties = new Properties();
        proxyProperties.setProperty(OracleConnection.PROXY_USER_NAME, proxyUserName);
        if (proxyPassword != null) {
            proxyProperties.setProperty(OracleConnection.PROXY_USER_PASSWORD, proxyPassword);
        }
        //below is what can take a few ms
        oraCon.openProxySession(OracleConnection.PROXYTYPE_USER_NAME, proxyProperties);
    }
}


import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;
import oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DelegatingDataSource;

class ProxyDelegatingDataSource extends DelegatingDataSource {

    private final PoolDataSource pds;
    private final String noPrivilegesUser;

    public ProxyDelegatingDataSource(PoolDataSource pds, String noPrivilegesUser) {
        super(pds);
        this.pds = pds;
        this.noPrivilegesUser = noPrivilegesUser;
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        Properties prprts = new Properties();
        prprts.put(ProxyConnectionLabelingCallback.USER_PROXY, getUserName());
        return getConnection(prprts);
    }

    public Connection getConnection(Properties prprts) throws SQLException {
        return pds.getConnection(prprts);
    }

    public Connection getConnection(String username, String password, Properties prprts) throws SQLException {
        return pds.getConnection(username, password, prprts);
    }

    private String getUserName() {
        return ProxyConnectionLabelingCallback.getUserName(noPrivilegesUser);
    }

}
```

Setup the Oracle privs:

```
create user JDBCPROXY identified by pass123;
create user MY_NOPRIV identified by pass123;
GRANT CONNECT TO JDBCPROXY;
GRANT CONNECT TO MY_NOPRIV;

alter user MY_NOPRIV grant connect through JDBCPROXY;
alter user USER1 grant connect through JDBCPROXY;
```

When the pool creates, all users will connect as JDBCPROXY proxied as MY_NOPRIV.
When "USER1" logs in, it will switch to JDBCPROXY proxied as USER1.

Setup Spring security and login as "USER1". I won't go into that.